# Send bytes multiple times within one HTTP connection. Java 8, Spring Boot, Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, http, tcp, video-streaming

My business case:

1. The user sends me an HTTP request. Example: http://ip:port/api/videostream
2. I handle this request.
3. I connect to another application over a TCP connection.
4. Application start sending me data (bytes) by this TCP connection.
5. I receive this data(bytes).
6. I send this data (bytes) to the user.

I need to send the data while the user watches this video stream. But how can I transfer data (bytes) to a user multiple times within a single Http request?

Answer (score 0):

Try just to open output stream in ServletRequest and write into this stream while there is data in TCP input stream.

Comment: I tried but it works another way, when I write in an output stream it looks like downloading one file. So user receives data one time.

Comment: Seems I don't understand the requirements. What do you mean by "So user receives data one time"? How can user receive data multiple times with one request?